# Binary classification of pairs with opposite labels

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function, gradient-descent

I have a data-set without labels, but I do have a way to get pairs of examples with opposite labels, that is given a pair `x,z` I know that their true labels are either `0,1` or `1,0`.

So, I am building a model that accepts pairs of samples as input, and learns to classify them with opposite labels. Assuming I have an arbitrary model for predicting a single sample, `y_hat = f(x)`, I am building a model with Keras that accepts pairs of samples `(x,z)` and outputs pairs of predictions, `f(x), f(z)`. I then use a custom loss function that drives the model towards the correct direction: Given that a regular binary classifier is trained using the Binary Cross Entropy (BCE) to make the predicted and desired output "close", I use the **negative** BCE. Also, since BCE is not symmetric, I symmetrize it. So, the loss function I give the `model.compile` method is:

```
from tensorflow import keras
bce = keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
def neg_sym_bce(y1, y2):
    return (- 0.5 * (bce(y1, y2) + bce(y2, y1)))
```

My problem is, this model fails to learn to classify even a **single** pair of my data (I get `f(x)~=f(z)~=0.5`), and if I try to train it with synthetic "easy" data, it takes hundreds of epochs to converge (also on a single pair).

This made me suspect that it has to do with a "vanishing gradient" problem. Indeed, when I plot (see below) the loss for a single pair, which is a function of 2 variables (the 2 outputs), it is evident that there is a wide plateau around the `0.5, 0.5` point. It is also evident that the global minima is, as expected, around the points `0,1` and `1,0`.
So, is there a way to deal with the vanishing gradient here? I read about the problem but the references I found deal with vanishing gradient in the network, not in the loss itself.

Or, is there another loss that can drive the model to predict opposite labels?

[image: negative symmetric BCE]

Comment: What is (0, 1) and (1,0)? Those seem like two distinct labels that are effectively "0" and "1".

Comment: @AndrewHolmgren that was shorthand notation, I meant that for input pair `x_1` and `x_2`, I don't know the labels `y_1` and `y_2` but I do know that `y_1 != y_2`

Comment: Similarly, are there times where you do know y_1 == y_2? If so, you probably want to use a contrastive loss.

Comment: @AndrewHolmgren, no, I don't have pairs with same labels.

Comment: actually, I may have access to a small data-set with `y_1==y_2` (and a vary large data-set of the dissimilar kind), so I'll have a look at this loss. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Think if your labels are always either 0,1 or 1,1 just use categorical_crossentropy for the loss.

Comment: This is a binary classification task, not multi-class. The labels are either `0` or `1`, I don't have labeled data but I do have pairs with opposite labels.

Comment: You can use categorical for binary classification you simply have 2 classes one is True then the other is False. Which to use depends on the format of your labels

Comment: Yes but this is not a regular supervised task. For categorical CE you need the true label for each sample, which I don't have